# Error while automating a form letter with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

My goal is to create a spread sheet that will feed information into a form letter, create a new folder, then save the letter to the new folder and repeat.

The code below completes one iteration, but runs into an error on the second loop

> remote procedure call failed

I think it is an issue with re-opening the template on the second run.

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range, fileName As String, Path As String


    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set objdoc = msWord.Documents.Add



    For i = 1 To 4

    fileName = Cells(i, 4).Value
     Path = "C:\Users\jarafat\Desktop\Variation1\" & fileName & "\" & fileName & ".docx"

If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jarafat\Desktop\Variation1\" & fileName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
  MkDir "C:\Users\jarafat\Desktop\Variation1\" & fileName
  End If

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open "C:\Users\jarafat\Desktop\Variation1\VariationTemplate1.docx"
        .Activate



        With .Activedocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            .Text = "#address"
            .Replacement.Text = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
        End With

        With .Activedocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            .Text = "#address1"
            .Replacement.Text = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
        End With

        With .Activedocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            .Text = "#Description"
            .Replacement.Text = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
        End With

        With msWord.Activedocument

        .SaveAs Path
        End With

        .Quit SaveChanges:=True
   End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to tell us exactly where the error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because the Word application is exited within the loop. So it's no longer available for the second (and following) loops:

```
    .Quit SaveChanges:=True
  End With
Next i
```

You need to do it like this, and it's a good idea to get into the habit of correctly *releasing* objects (set to `Nothing`) to outside applications, as well.

```
  End With
Next i
msWord.Quit SaveChanges:=True
Set msWord = Nothing
```

I also recommend you declare and use a `Document` object rather than relying on `ActiveDocument`. There's always the chance that the active document isn't the one you expect. For example:

```
'At the beginning of the code
Dim doc as Object
'More code...
Set doc = .Documents.Open "C:\Users\jarafat\Desktop\Variation1\VariationTemplate1.docx"
'No need to activate, now...
'Activate
With doc.Content.Find
  'And so on until...
  .SaveAs Path
  'You're done with the document, so release the object
  Set doc = Nothing
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Cindy's solution...

Instead of repeating this multiple times with slight variations:

```
  With .Activedocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        .Text = "#address"
        .Replacement.Text = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
    End With
```

you can make a separate sub:

```
Sub ReplaceText(doc As Object, findWhat, replaceWith)
      With doc.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            .Text = findWhat
            .Replacement.Text = replaceWith

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1         'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            .Execute Replace:=2  'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
      End With
End sub
```

...and call it from within your loop

```
Dim doc
With msWord
    .Visible = True
    Set doc = .Documents.Open("C:\Users\jarafat\Desktop\Variation1\VariationTemplate1.docx")

    ReplaceText doc, "#address", ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    ReplaceText doc, "#address1", ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    ReplaceText doc, "#Description", ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
    'etc
```

Comment: This is great, this is exactly what I needed to develop my skills. Thank you so much